# Function for regaining park capacity for visitors?

Tags: function, system, equation, systemdynamics, vensim

I am getting used to Vensim for Modelling System Dynamics. To train, I am busy with a System Dynamics of Park Visitors. Where I have modelling the following Stock and Flow Diagram:
[image: SFD]

For the equation of 'Max Capacity' I have defined it as:

> max capacity = - ( 0.05 * amount of visitors )

And also I have set the initial value to 400.000 visitors per year as a max.

This means that the carrying capacity gets lower by 5% of the total amount of visitors of the previous year. This results into the following diagram:
[image: diagram2]

Now I want to make the park regain its capacity again. I initially thought of something like:

> IF THEN ELSE( Max Capacity < 250000 , 0.05 * Max Capacity, - ( 0.05 *
>   Amount of visitors ))

This gives the following diagram:
[image: diagram3]

As you see, it doesn't really it just prevents the capacity from ever continuing to decay with 5%.

**How can I make it so that the capacity regains again to 400.000 over time?**

Comment: Hello! Could you give us a reproducible example? Because in this example there's no all equations required to reproduce the behavior observed in the charts.

Comment: You says that the equation `max capacity` depends of the `amount of visitors`, but in the diagram there's no relationship between these variables...